# Consistency Check inconsistency logging disabled, too many inconsistencies on VD: 0

Tags: lsi, megaraid

We recently purchased an LSI MegaRAID 9266-8i SAS RAID card to replace a failed card in our NAS.  Setup of the card went smoothly, I updated the firmware, set up RAID6 with hotswap, and let it initialize.  Every so often (once a week or so?) we get flooded with the following error:

```
Controller ID:  0  Patrol Read aborted on PD:   -:-:0
```

This error repeats for each of the drives (12 total.)  After all of the errors are sent to us (via email as well as an alert on the device), we get this error:

```
Consistency Check inconsistency logging disabled, too many inconsistencies on VD:       0
```

Also, something new that happened today, the MegaRAID software is reporting the array is 'optimal', but looking at the disks shows that one of the drives has a very high media error count (the rest have 0).  Anyone have any idea if this is just a failed drive despite the status being 'optimal?

Comment: The drive *may* fail soon, yes. As for the "too many inconsistencies", I had that as well. A "full initialization" kept that error away. (Warning: Removes all data!)

Comment: Backup soon if you haven't already. That sounds like a failing drive. Try pulling the SMART data from the drive with the high media error count. Then again, it could just be as simple as a loose connection - happens more often than you'd think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience the patrol read is aborted because it is run at the same time as consistency check. Try rescheduling the patrol read time.  here is info on the consistency check aborted if on RAID1 or RAID10

https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5092480

Comment: That was the issue.  Rescheduling things fixed the problem.